# Silicon/silicon dioxide interface

Tags: optics, semiconductor-physics

Suppose we have an interface of silicon/silicondioxide. If we shine light on the top surface electron-hole pairs are generated in silicon. since there is always a field directing from surface to bulk in silicon (taking n type silicon), electron moves to the bulk and hole moves to the interface states. Is there any chance of holes being reached in silicon dioxide surface?

Comment: The question as it exists is unclear. You should perhaps justify why you believe 'there is always a field directing from surface to bulk in silicon'. Then, clarify what exactly you are asking for in the last sentence - currently it does not make sense.

Comment: You seem to be confusing a semiconductor junction with bulk semiconductor material.  Photocells work like what you describe, but only when the photon hits in a semiconductor junction.  The principle doesn't work in bulk semiconductor material, whether doped or not.